# Does HTTP 1.0 support compression?

Tags: http

HTTP 1.0 vs HTTP 1.1 compression/decompression support.

I know that technically HTTP 1.0 supports compression/decompression (but it depends on browser as I understand), but a lot resources say that HTTP 1.1 has enhanced support and can't find reasonable answer to my question.

So the question is: **Does HTTP 1.0 support compression and if yes under what conditions and what are those enhancements in HTTP 1.1?**

Comment: HTTP 1.0: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945

Comment: HTTP 1.1: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616

Comment: Both documents are easy reads. Compare section 3.5 of the first document with section 3.5 of the second document.

Comment: I'd be more curious why you need http 1.0 support.

Comment: @selbie it's for general education purpose)